Fastendpoints with Swagger dont shows summary texts
I use fast endpoints with swagger
I can see that the endpoints get found and are shown in the swagger document but the summary informations arent shown
here my Configure
public override void Configure()
{
    this.Get("/devicelogs/{DeviceId}/");
    this.AllowAnonymous();

    Summary(s => {
        s.Summary = "short summary goes here";
        s.Description = "long description goes here";
        s.Responses[200] = "ok response description goes here";
        s.Responses[403] = "forbidden response description goes here";
    });
    this.Description(
        b => b
            .WithName("GetDeviceLog")
            .Accepts<GetDeviceLogRequest>("application/json")
            .Produces<GetDeviceLogResponse>(200, "application/json")
    );
}


relevant parts of startup:
 services
                .AddFastEndpoints()
                .AddSwaggerDocument(
                    x =>
                    {
                        x.Description = "Proxy Http Endpoints";
                        x.Title = "Proxy Http Endpoints";
         
                    });

and then
app.UseSwaggerGen(x =>
                {
                    x.DocumentName = "Proxy Http Endpoints";
                });
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapFastEndpoints();
                 });

the output
what am I Missing?

This question is similar to: Fastendpoints swagger summary not displaying. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Dĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ I do use the swagger extensions from fast endpoints , the problem describes in the linked post uses the extensions which are not from fastendpoints to add swagger

i see AddSwaggerDocument() in your code, which is not right. see here for the correct methods.

Oh sorry I was so blind. you were right! Thank you!
